# ADODB.connection open returning application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, adodb

I have the below code and it is returning an error:

> Application defined or object defined error.

```
Public Sub TestConnection()
    Dim conn
    Set conn = New ADODB.connection
    CONSTRING = "Provider=NZOLEDB;Data Source=location;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=username; Password=password;"
    conn.Open CONSTRING

End Sub
```

Any idea why this is happening? I am not substituting the variables etc. just typing them directly into the string.

Comment: just to add i have the ADO 6.0 library referenced.

Comment: Do you add reference of `ADODB` to your project?

Comment: if you mean activex data objects 6.0 then yes. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about its version - But yes it is `Microsoft ActiveX Data Object`;).

Comment: Can you tell us the line number the error occurs on?

Comment: Do you have the Netezza provider installed?

Comment: @bond   conn.Open CONSTRING

Comment: @GTG i don't think i do, do you know where i can find it?

Comment: No, @MichaelWa, don't know anything about that provider. I just saw in the connection string that you are using that provider, so I see that you need it and it might just explain this error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just to add a reference to [`Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (ADO)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And [for more information about using ADODB in Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168335).

---

As Microsoft examples, I suggest you to use this type of declaration:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
```